# Get data into Graphite/Carbon using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, grafana, graphite, graphite-carbon

I've got a Grafana docker image running with Graphite/Carbon. Getting data using CLI works, example:

`` echo "local.random.diceroll $(((RANDOM%6)+1)) `date +%s`" | nc localhost 2003; ``

The following Python 2 code also works:

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((CARBON_SERVER, CARBON_PORT))
sock.sendall(message)
sock.close()
```

`message` is a string containing `key value timestamp` and this works, the data can be found. So the Grafana docker image is accepting data.

I wanted to get this working in Python 3, but the `sendall` function requires bytes as parameter. The code change is:

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((CARBON_SERVER, CARBON_PORT))
sock.sendall(str.encode(message))
sock.close()
```

Now the data isn't inserted and I can't figure out why. I tried this on a remote machine (same network) and on the local server. I also tried several packages (graphiti, graphiteudp), but they all seem to fail to insert the data. They also don't show any error message.

The simple example for `graphiteudp` doesn't work either on the [Github page](https://github.com/derpston/python-graphiteudp)

Got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\n` to the message you send. I have tried it with Python 3, and that works.